# AlertDialog has leaked window

Tags: java, android

Есть вспомогательный класс, который проверяет наличие интернета. Запускаю из него алерт диалог, вылетает некритичная ошибка, когда жму на кнопку "Выход":

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView
that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:918)
```

Получается что при выходе из приложения алерт диалог не закрывает окно. Собственно, сама функция:

```
public void getInetSettingsDialog(final Context ctx){
    //mContext = ctx;
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    //b.setMessage("Перейти в настройки?");
    b.setTitle("Нет интернет соединения");
    b.setPositiveButton("Настройки", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
       }
    });
    b.setNegativeButton("Выход", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           ((Activity) ctx).finish();
       }
    });
    b.show();
}
```

Подскажите как можно избавиться от нее?

Comment: попробуйте делать также dismiss диалогу перед завершением Activity

Comment: пробовал и так. все равно при выходе из приложения вылетает ошибка

Comment: Возможно, у вас идёт попытка показа диалога после `onPause` актвити. Попробуйте завести `boolean` переменную, коей в `onResume` присваивать `true` и `false` в `onPause` и только если она `true`  - показывать диалог. Ну или в `onPause`/`onStop`/`onDestroy` вызывать dismiss на диалоге.

Comment: @IvanVovk я все же осмелюсь уточнить, вы делали dismiss 
перед строчкой ((Activity) ctx).finish();? Потому что это должно быть так но вы почему то решили что диалог закрывать не обязательно:)

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii да, закрывал диалог перед вызовом ((Activity) ctx).finish(); результат одинаковый.

Comment: @IvanVovk тогда возможно ваша логика построена таким образом что вы пытаетесь показать диалог после того как это активити закрылось.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал как вы написали, добавил переменную. Теперь ясно понимаю, что ошибка кроется где-то в onResume. получается у меня 2 окна при запуске приложения и второе как раз вызывает ошибку.

Comment: @IvanVovk, покажите когда и как запускаете метод показа диалога.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб банально просто=) getInetSettingsDialog(); убрал из запуска onCreate() данный метод, оставил только в onResume - ошибка ушла! Благодарю за помощь! Ставьте ваш ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, ошибка вызвана тем, что диалог пытается отобразиться не между методами жизненного цикла активити - `onResume()`-`onPause()`. Если отображать диалог в промежутке меж этими методами - проблем быть не должно.

Если диалог отображается по к-л событию типа наличия/отсутствие интернета, кое может придти вне указанного промежутка, то вы можете не отображать его, отталкиваясь от boolean переменной, коей вы назначаете `true` в `onResume()` и `false` в `onPause()`